# Update a BLOB in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to update an existing pdf image in a blob with a new PDF image.

Using the Script below

```
create or replace directory BLOBS as 'c:\scripts\blob\';

DECLARE 
  v_lob    BLOB; 
  l_bfile  bfile; 
  amt      NUMBER; 

BEGIN 

l_bfile := bfilename('BLOBS', 'releaseofinformation.pdf' ); 

SELECT td.TEMPLATE_IMAGE 
INTO v_lob 
FROM template_definition td 
WHERE td.internal_name='AUTH_FOR_RELE_OF_INFO_FORM'
FOR UPDATE; 

amt := dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ); 

dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile ,dbms_lob.file_readonly); 
dbms_lob.OPEN(v_lob,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
dbms_lob.loadfromfile( v_lob, l_bfile ,amt); 

dbms_output.put_line('File length is: '||dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile )); 
dbms_output.put_line('Loaded length is: '||dbms_lob.getlength(v_lob)); 
dbms_lob.close(v_lob);
dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile ); 

END; 
/
```

The directory with the file is on the server for Oracle to use. 
The script appears to run and reports the file length of the new file for both in the output.  When I query the record and select the blob in a popup editor, the blob appears unchanged.

I tried then to update the procedure to update the blob with an empty_blob() and then run the script only to now have an empty blob.

Thoughts and ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you committed in the session executing the script before you query the blob in the popup editor? Or is that the same session? (It might not be if you are using for example Toad.)

Comment: I am running a datafix script and it reports that the procedure ran successfully and reports the file lengths. I then go into Toad to verify the blob update, but as the column is empty now it remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but I had to manually update the record/field to empty_blob(), Commit that change, and then I could proceed with updating the blob with the file image.